# Bootstrap: Floating Image between other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 image">Image</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 title">Title</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 description"> Description </div>    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 button">Button</div>
</div>
```

For smaller devices I am trying to float the Title above the image and the description and button below the image. This seems simple enough but I just cant seem to get it right

http://jsfiddle.net/mxptxszx/

Answer (score 1):

you can set the position to absolute for the title and add padding-top(same as your .title height) to the .row

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mxptxszx/12/)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .title {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .row {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has the ability to re-order columns using `push` or `pull` css classes.

You can view the source/example here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12 title">Title</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-xs-12 image">Image</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 description"> Description </div>    
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 button">Button</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s8h18kme/

It does actually modify the larger (SM) view a bit due to the way it works. It would be helpful understanding the exact design you wish for the larger view to so I can help with resetting it back. For example on the larger view do you wish it to have the image on the left and the 3 other section on the right(in order of how you had them originally?)

Comment: Thank you, I should been more clear, the way that it is set up with the image on the left and the title, description and button on the right is the intended view for desktops and tablets. The view with the title floating on top is what I intend for smart phones